# How to use React-native's NavigationExperimental with Relay?

Tags: react-native, relayjs

Restating my previous question on github onto StackOverflow,
https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1010

I was trying to find an example usage of react native's NavigationExperimental APIs integrated with Relay, but couldn't find one.

Is it possible in the current states of NavigationExperimental and Relay?

If yes, could someone provide a basic example?

If not, what are the issues that need to be resolved in order to make them work together?

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationExperimental` is a bleeding edge API; I think you might have to just try it out and see! I took a quick look at the docs and I suspect that if your navigation "route" objects were something like `{key: string, relayRoute: RelayRoute, component: Component}`, then your `renderScene` function could just render a `RelayRootContainer` with that route and component. I'd recommend trying it and publish your results!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/joonhocho/react-native-router-relay-todo. It uses react-router-native that uses NavigationExperimental.